# Perforce Error: Syncing your clientview to head-revisions ... Error: [Create Client-Spec]

Tags: perforce

Can't find anywhere the source of such error. I'm trying to create my workspace for a project on a Depot and when syncing for the first time I get this:

> Syncing your clientview to head-revisions ...
>
> Error: [Create Client-Spec]

What is this error about?

Comment: What tool are you using which produces this message?

Comment: Line Command from Linux (Putty) Terminal. That is my Virtual MAchine where I'm trying to run sync a project. :-(

Comment: Yes, but what *command* did you issue? Did you run 'p4 sync'? 'p4 client'? Something else entirely? I've never seen such an error message from the default p4 client, so perhaps either you are using a custom client application, or you have installed a broker, or some server triggers?

Comment: Just Find out. It was p4 sync but it was VPN firewall issue !!! Many Thks for trying to support !!!